# Delete Label on Button Click and Other label Move Up

Tags: ios

I am Developing IOS App. Create Label and Button when I select didSelectRowAtIndexPath that create properly. but When i Clicked button to delete label and button delete perfectly.but problem is that label's not move up after deleted label and button. and change the index value of the label's after deleted label. please help thanks in advance.

```
Code..  

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    y =  y + 40;
    count++;

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",selectedCell);

    NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    _label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y, 200.0f, 30.0f)];
    [_label.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [_label.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    _label.text = str;
    _label.tag = indexPath.row;
    [self.view addSubview:_label];

    _button =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220.0f,y, 30.0f, 30.0f)];
    [_button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [_button.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [_button setTag:indexPath.row];
    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_button];
}
- (IBAction)buttonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{

    y = y - 40;

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSInteger index = button.tag;

    [[sender viewWithTag:index] removeFromSuperview];

    _label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:index];
    [_label removeFromSuperview];

    _label =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y, 200.0f, 30.0f)];
    _label.tag = index;
    [self.view addSubview:_label];



    _label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:index + 1];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, 200.0f, 30.0f);
    _label.tag = index;
    [self.view addSubview:_label];

    _button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:index+1];
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(220.0f,y, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    _button.tag = index;
    _button.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_button];
}
```

Comment: Use a UIStackView for this. In a UIStackView this is more or less automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove this code in your method `buttonTouchUpInside`

```
_label =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y, 200.0f, 30.0f)];
 _label.tag = index;
 [self.view addSubview:_label];
```

because you are adding new label at same frame

And write this method like this way

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{

    y = y - 40;

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSInteger index = button.tag;

    [[sender viewWithTag:index] removeFromSuperview];

    _label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:index];
    [_label removeFromSuperview];



    _label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:index + 1];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, 200.0f, 30.0f);
    _label.tag = index;


    _button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:index+1];
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(220.0f,y, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    _button.tag = index;
    _button.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];

}
```

No need this statement

```
[self.view addSubview:_label];

[self.view addSubview:_button];
```

once you added in your view

Comment: This is not Working.